# django display content of a manytomanyfield

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I started using django framework just a few days ago and i desperately need some help with my application.

It consists of client,project,admin,and admin payment classes where the admin_payment holds the ids of the admins and projects among other stuff.

My question is how i can display the "administrator's name" of each "project" in my admin listing of projects? the project class itself does not hold the administrator ids (the Admin_Payment does)

Currently i have the following structure: (striped down)

models.py

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    admin_name = models.CharField(unique = True, blank = False, null = False, max_length = 128, verbose_name = u'admin full name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.admin_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        verbose_name = u'Admin Info'

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name = u'Client')
    description = models.ForeignKey(Description, verbose_name = u'project description')
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(Admin, verbose_name = u'Administrators', through = 'Admin_Payment')

class Admin_Payment(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Admin, verbose_name = u'Administrator')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name = u'project')
```

admin.py (striped down)

```
class AdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Admin

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    radio_fields = {'position': admin.HORIZONTAL, 'solution': admin.HORIZONTAL}
    inlines = [AdminInline, ]
    list_display = ['client','description','admin_name']
```

Clients and Descriptions appear correctly in the project listing but the admin names are not

Any help is appreciated
(sorry if i posted anything that doesnt make sense , i am a newbie in python and django)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Displaying the contents of `ManyToMany` field isn't supported by default by django, because the database will be queried for each row of the results. You can display it yourself by [adding a method to your `Project`-model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ....
    def admin_names(self):
        return ', '.join([a.admin_name for a in self.admins.all()])
    admin_names.short_description = "Admin Names"
```

and put `admin_names` in your `list_display` fields!

Comment: That worked great thanks. Any idea how i can add a filter for each admin?

Comment: is it possible to add a verbose_name to the returned value?

Comment: @Thordin9: i've added the answer to fit yourquestion, additionally see the doc at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Useful answer. If you want to add the value from the `__unicode__` method on your model without rewriting it, try: `return ', '.join([str(a) for a in self.admins.all()])`. It works fine if you don't use the `__str__` method [as stated on documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode).

Comment: Is there a way to show this collection in nested list?