# Django: verbose name for manytomanyfield in a modelform

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm looking to add a human-readable name to a manytomanyfield that will be displayed in a modelform. I've already been here: [django display content of a manytomanyfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564086/django-display-content-of-a-manytomanyfield) and that solution doesn't work for modelfields, unless I've misunderstood. I'm sure there's a way to do it, I just haven't been able to figure it out. Does anyone know?

Comment: Do you mean displaying many2many items in ChangeList admin view?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [a verbose_name field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name)?

```
foo = models.ManyToManyField("app.Model", ..., verbose_name="bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way:

```
class A(models.Model):        
    foo = models.CharField("Foo", max_length = 20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Human-readable"
        verbose_name_plural = "Human-readable"
class B(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(A, related_name='if_you_need')
```

Your bars field should display as "Human-readable".