# How to show a Many-to-Many field in my django HTML Template?

Tags: python, django

I have one many to many field in my model.py

in that case i'm getting data as a queryset. But i want data as list. How to achieve that ?

Comment: did you try `{{ rt.Developer }}` in the template?

Comment: Hey @yuv , yes i have tried that , in that case i getting hello.developer.None. here hellp is my app name and developer is the field name

Comment: sorry, i  got wrong.. But I posted the answer.. Please check that out

Comment: Thanks @Yuv 
But if i want that m2m field while edit (django form) how to get that ? can yo please help me. i'm totally new to this django platform

Comment: Do you use Django ModelForm? If so then you can handle the post request method in the views.py file. Check if the form is valid and save. It will automatically save the model data in the database.

Comment: @yuv, yes i'm using django form. But not able to achieve that. I'll post another question regarding this . with the code you will better understand my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233840/discussion-between-rika-das-and-yuv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
{% for rt in JIRA %}
{% for dev in rt.Developer.all %}
<td>{{dev}} </td>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey @yuv can you please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68062913/15853459

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are more than one variable in Developer model. I think you are showing your data in a table data for that to work you should assign a **str**(self) function for the Developer model as it is mentioned below link:

[django display content of a manytomanyfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564086/django-display-content-of-a-manytomanyfield)

I hope it is clear.

Comment: Hey i have updated my question. there i passed my data and in your code i'm not able to understand why login is required