# How to do auto assign in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project. where there's two table one is developer table and another one is Jira table. developer table and jira table are connected with m2m relation.

here's my model.py

```
class developer(models.Model):  
    Developer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Expertise = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Availability_Hours = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Developer_Name

class jira(models.Model):  
    Jira_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Jira_Story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Short_Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Story_Points = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Sprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    DX4C_Object = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Developer = models.ManyToManyField(developer)
    Sandbox = models.ForeignKey(environments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'Mainline': None},blank=True, null=True)
  

    def developer_assigned(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.Developer.all()])
```

Now my query is how to set a rule where if Dx4c object is changing then automatically one developer will assign based on the rule?
here's my view.py

```
def dependency_management(request):
    jira_story = jira.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'hello/Dependency_Management.html', {'JIRA': jira_story})
```

I want to make that dynamic. I mean if  everytime I add any new DX4C object then without the code change that particular developer will assign based on the rule

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```py
class Developer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    expertise = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    availability_hours = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Jira(models.Model):
    Jira_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    story_points = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    DX4C_Object = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    developers = models.ManyToManyField(developer)
    sandbox = models.ForeignKey(
        environments,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'Mainline': None},
        blank=True, null=True,
    )

    def developer_assigned(self):
        return ",".join(self.developers.values_list('name', flat=True))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if pk := getattr(self, 'id', 0):
            old_value = self.__class__.objects.get(id=pk).DX4C_Object
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if pk and self.DX4C_Object != old_value:
            # do sth
```

Comment: Hi @WaketZheng, i'm not getting what to do after if not created: how do i set rule to assign a developer based of changing the dx4c object

Comment: Get old version before save and then compare it after save. Code updated.